# CLI Doctrine 2 - index already defined

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity, identifier

I'm trying to create my database with Doctrine 2 from my PHP entity.

Here is my code from the class Team :

```
<?php
// Team.php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="team")
 **/
class Team
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string",length=30)
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $function;

    /**
     * @Column(type="text")
     * @var string
     **/
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="File")
     * @JoinColumn(name="fileID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $img;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="File")
     * @JoinColumn(name="fileID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $cv;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Language")
     * @JoinColumn(name="languageID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $lang;

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getFunction()
    {
        return $this->function;
    }

    public function setFunction($function)
    {
        $this->function = $function;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getImg()
    {
        return $this->img;
    }

    public function setImg($img)
    {
        $this->img = $img;
    }

    public function getCv()
    {
        return $this->cv;
    }

    public function setCv($cv)
    {
        $this->cv = $cv;
    }

    public function getLang()
    {
        return $this->lang;
    }

    public function setLang(Language $language)
    {
        $this->lang = $language;
    }
}
```

And the error :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
An index with name 'uniq_c4e0a61f93cb796c' was already defined on table 'team'
```

Doctrine is loaded from composer and used with Windows CMD (if that can help).

I've seen that an issue has been reported for v.2.5.0 so I loaded 2.4.7 but same error, so I tried dev-master but still the same.

I also tried removing the composite Id and replaced it by a simple generated @Id, or even none (Doctrine was then saying No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Team").

This code was working with v.2.4.2 but the point is to update the tools used for this project.

Do somebody know how I could do this ?

Comment: Could you provide whole entity? It's annotations in particular.

Comment: Sure thing ! Here is the whole file. Note that I can create the database without the class Team, it's the only file that don't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well well, I found the problem :

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="File")
 * @JoinColumn(name="fileID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $img;

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="File")
 * @JoinColumn(name="fileID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $cv;
```

More precisely `@JoinColumn(name="fileID", referencedColumnName="id")`, the column name `fileID` is the same for both.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: is this a bug in doctrine or we cannot use one column for more than once?

Comment: That was an error from me. You cannot have two identical column names which is pretty logical.

Answer (score 0):

You problem lies here:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Language")
 * @JoinColumn(name="languageID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $lang;
```

You have to remove the `@Id` from your `$lang` property. Associations should not be marked as entity identifiers.

The `@Id` annotation is used to mark the primary key (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-id). Your association is not a primary key, when migrating the schema doctrine will attempt to add an index and map a foreign key (depending on the configuration).

Since you marked the association as an identifier this conflicts with your `$id` key.

Comment: I removed this `@Id` and the other one on `$user` because it's also a FK.

Comment: Sorry hit enter too fast.. No it's not, I also removed the other Id because it's also a FK and created a generated one but still not ok. It's odd because I have another entity working with a composite Id which one is `@Id` on `$lang`.

Comment: Are you running a `doctrine:schema:update` on an existing database or `doctrine:schema:create` on an empty database?

Comment: Create on an empty one